# object size of class which is inherited from virtual base classes?

Tags: c++, object, size, virtual

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class grandparent
{
        public:
        int x;
};

class parent1 :  virtual public grandparent
{
        public:
        int y;
};

class parent2 :  virtual public grandparent
{
        public:
        int z;
};

class child : public parent1, public parent2
{

};
int main()
{
        child obj;

        cout<<sizeof(obj)<<endl;

}
```

> Output: 20

```
  #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class grandparent
    {
            public:
            int x;
    };

    class parent1 :   public grandparent
    {
            public:
            int y;
    };

    class parent2 :   public grandparent
    {
            public:
            int z;
    };

    class child : public parent1, public parent2
    {

    };
    int main()
    {
            child obj;

            cout<<sizeof(obj)<<endl;

    }
```

> Output: 16

When parent1 and parent2 inherited without virtual then I got object size of child is 16? but when parent1 and parent2 inherited with virtual then why I got size of child 20 instead of 12?s

Comment: Why are your examples the same?

Comment: So why is this interesting?  It's an implementation detail that will vary from one compiler to another (or more likely from one compiler with one set of options to any other combination of compilers and options.)

Comment: @LogicStuff More interesting: why are the outputs different?

Comment: see i changed the code.... @LogicStuff

Comment: @DaleWilson... means why 8 byte is increased because of virtual only?

Comment: @erip By mistake i put wrong code before....

Comment: Now u can check @erip